# adding an eventhandler to datagridview

Tags: c#, eventhandler

I am trying to add a key event handler to a Datagridview.

I have added this (below) to my code:L

```
private void DgvDb_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    colI = DgvDb.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex;
    if (colI < 3 | colI == 12 | colI == 13 | colI == 15 | colI == 16 | colI == 17 | colI == 18 | colI == 19 | colI == 20 | colI == 21 | colI == 22)
    {
        vlue = Convert.ToString(DgvDb[colI, rowI - 1].Value);
        DgvDb[colI, rowI].Value = vlue;
    }
}
```

It shows "0 references" and in the code there is a redline under `DgvDB` saying it *"does not exist in the current context"*.   In the rest of the program, `DgvDB` is recognized.

I looked at similar code elsewhere in my application and looked at a reference in the `XXX.Designer.cs`.

I added to my designer under //DgvDB

```
this.DgvDB.KeyUp += new System.Windows.Forms.KeyEventHandler(this.DgvDB_KeyUp);
```

Here, `DgvDB_KeyUp` is redlined saying does not contain a definition for `DgvDB_KeyUp`.

Comment: _"I added to my designer under..."_ - **Do not** edit your `.designer.cs` files because any and all changes you make to it will be lost whenever you _do so much as sneeze_ in the direction of a `Form` subclass in Visual Studio.

Comment: winforms, .net Framework 4.x ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you wanted to write`if (colI < 3 || colI == 12 || colI == 13 || ....`.

Answer (score 0):

Double check if the event is tied to the datagridview and thats all:

[image]

You should see 1 reference.

Please notice,do not modify the designer since it can be automatically changed.

Comment: This is absolutely what I know.   I converted my vb code and I guess this is the first time I added Key_up in C#.   Thank you ever so much!

Answer (score 0):

You could instead have an array of column names and test against them rather than indices.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    /// <summary>
    /// Add each column name for logic in DgvDBOnKeyUp
    /// </summary>
    private readonly string[] _columns = new[]
    {
        "Column1", "Column2", "Column3", "Column12",
    };
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        Shown += OnShown;
    }

    private void OnShown(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DgvDB.KeyUp += DgvDBOnKeyUp;
    }

    private void DgvDBOnKeyUp(object? sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (_columns.Contains(DgvDB.CurrentCell.OwningColumn.Name))
        {
            // do your task
        }
    }
}
```